# How to do custom shapes of image like star and cicle?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I want implement the custom shapes for ImageView like star ,circle , heart like this . can anyone suggest for ...
Thanxs in advance ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go for this link [CustomImageViewShape](https://github.com/MostafaGazar/CustomShapeImageView)